# Terraform authenticating to azure by service principal and client secret

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

Whenever I run `terraform plan` command I have to put **client id, secret id, tenant id and subscription id** manually.

Here is my setup

I have set env variables in my **.zprofile**

```
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=*********
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=*********
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=*********
export ARM_TENANT_ID=*********
```

if I want to see them echo $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID it does print out its value

In my **providers.tf** file this is the code

```
# Configuration options
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
  client_id       = var.CLIENT_ID
  client_secret   = var.CLIENT_SECRET
  tenant_id       = var.TENANT_ID
  features {

  }

}
```

And in my **variables.tf** file the code looks like this

```
variable "SUBSCRIPTION_ID" {
  
}

variable "CLIENT_ID" {
  
}

variable "CLIENT_SECRET" {
  
}

variable "TENANT_ID" {
  
}
```

so when I run `terraform plan` commands the terminal prompts me to put all ids manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So finally I have found the solution.

If you have multiple subscriptions of Azure (you are working for multiple clients) then the first thing is that you need to check which is your current subscription.
Run this command to check all subscriptions

```
az account tenant list
```

and run this command to change switch your subscription

```
az login --tenant <myTenantID>
```

and now you can run any Azure cli command and changes will be reflected on your current subscription

Answer (score 0):

***Authenticating to azure by service principal and client secret using terraform:***

*I tried to authenticate with*  `AzureAD service principal` *in my environment after finding a* [workaround](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret) *and was able to perform it successfully.*

***I've setup env variables in*** `azCLI` as shown here:

```bash
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="<subscription_id>"
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="<client_id>"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="<tenant_id>"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="<client_secret>"
```

To authenticate service principal, we need to give some role permissions and API Permissions as well.

***Required Permissions to enable:***

Goto `Roles and Administrators` under `Azure Active Directory` through portal. There are certain administrator positions that come with default configuration. Actively enable the roles of "***Application Administrator, Global Administrator, and User Administrator***".

[image]

[image]

[image]

*and*

Goto `API permissions` under registered `App registration` and add application permissions for microsoft graph as its the main source to authenticate to Portal and enable below given permissions by clicking on `Add permission`.

***App registration:***

[image]

To check, I created a resource group and applying a dev tag for it after successful authentication.

***Provider.tf***

```bash
variable "client_secret" {}
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "2.30.0" //Give the latest version
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}

provider "azuread" {
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id     = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = var.client_secret
  tenant_id     = "<tenant_id>"
  features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "t_rg" {
  name     = "<resourcegroupName>"
  location = "<location>"

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init`:

[image]

***After setting up everything, I executed*** `terraform plan`, ***it is asking for*** `client_secret` ***only not*** `client_id`:

[image]

***Executed*** `Terraform apply`:

[image]

***Authenticated & deployed successfully in Portal:***

[image]

***Applied tags successfully for resourcegroup as given:***

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have 2 accounts of 2 different companies, Company A and Company B. With Company A I have no issue and if I replicate everything what I do on Company's A infra but that does not work on Company' B Infra. 
I have checked all permissions and it is the same as company A but I still have to put them manually but when I try to authenticate for Company A it does not ask me put any ID manually. It grabs everything from Env variables.
The issue is why I have to put manually hehe.
Issue is why I have to put them manually hehe

Comment: Thanks. Only client_id is asking manually or tenant and everything?

Comment: All 4 IDs (client id, secret id, tenant id and subscription id) manually.

Comment: Are you trying in powershell or bash?

Comment: If you can try the same process as I described above, it should work. Because I tried again in my environment, its working fine.

Comment: you are saying that you don't need to put any id? right?

Comment: Are you giving `variables.tf` separately? If we setup all id's as env variables, then no need to provide a separate variable file. May be that's why it is asking you to provide id again.